# Use Regex instead of Case When?

Tags: mysql, sql

It seems like I have this query that takes CPU usage. I wonder if it might be faster to just use regex instead:

```sql
GROUP_CONCAT(
    CASE
        WHEN b.column_1 LIKE '%Principal%' THEN CONCAT(a.start_date,  ' ~ ' , a.end_date, ' ', REPLACE(b.column_1, 'School Principal of', 'Principal') , ';', CHAR(10 using utf8) )
        ELSE ''
    END
ORDER BY a.start_date ASC SEPARATOR '') AS roles
```

The idea is to have an output similar to "2021-01-01 ~ 2022-01-01 Principal" wherein `column_1` is like "School Principal of" or "Company Principal of".

Regex of `column_1` is like "^.*(principal).*$". Yeah, basically just grabbing "Principal" if it exists and if not then completely remove the whole string.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: *I wonder if it might be faster* - Can't you answer this yourself by using EXPLAIN and running both versions and comparing the results? Whether it's *faster* is going to depend entirely on your data, and we don't have it. And how can it *seem like* you have that query? You either have it or you don't.

Comment: What's the goal? faster data retrieval or shorter query? and how will the end result look like? a single line per userid (I assume there is one) or multiple lines?

Comment: Yeah, goal here is to have a faster data retrieval.

> And how can it seem like you have that query? You either have it or you don't.

Yeah, it's because I'm not sure how to do this using regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know the fixed format of the output you want in the case of a match, I don't see the need to even do the replacement on `column_1`.  Use this version:

```sql
GROUP_CONCAT(
    CASE WHEN b.column_1 LIKE '%Principal%'
         THEN CONCAT(a.start_date,  ' ~ ' , a.end_date, ' Principal')
         ELSE '' END
    ORDER BY a.start_date ASC SEPARATOR '') AS roles
```

Note that you *could* use `REGEXP` here to match `Principal`, but unless you are really worried about word boundaries, I might stick with the `LIKE` approach you are currently using.

Comment: Oh that it is rather better. Yeah, I was wondering if I could replace `CASE WHEN` with some regex.

Comment: You may replace the `LIKE` logic with `REGEXP`, but I would leave the `CASE` expression there, so that you should empty string for non matches.

Answer (score 1):

- `LIKE` is usually faster than the equivalent `REGEXP`.
- `LIKE` without a leading wildcard can make use of an index; I do not believe that `REGEXP` does likewise.
- `REGEXP` (`RLIKE`) has a much richer set of pattern matching capabilities.
- `REGEXP 'Principal'` is the equivalent of `LIKE '%Principal%'`
- `.` matches exactly one character.
- Use `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` for word boundaries before 8.0; use `\\b` in 8.0.

What is the context of your query?  If you are scanning a table *only* for this info, then moving the `LIKE` to the outside `WHERE` would be faster than checking every row inside the `CASE`.